# How to implement Jackson custom serialization outside a domain bean?

Tags: java, dojo, jackson, dgrid, java-custom-serialization

I have a Spring managed bean...

```
@Component("Foobean")
@Scope("prototype")
public class foobean {

    private String bar1;
    private String bar2;

    public String getBar1() {
        return bar1;
    }
    public void setBar1(String bar1) {
    this.bar1 = bar1;
    }
    public String getBar2() {
    return bar2;
    }
    public void setBar2(String bar2) {
    this.bar2 = bar2;
    }
}
```

...and because I am using Dojo Dgrid to display an ArrayList of this bean, I am returning it into the controller as a JSON string:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/bo")
public class FooController {
     @Autowired
     private FooService fooService

     @RequestMapping("action=getListOfFoos*")
     @ResponseBody 
     public String clickDisplayFoos(
        Map<String, Object> model) {

    List<Foobean> foobeans = fooService.getFoobeans();

    ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String FooJson = null;
    try {
        FooJson = objMapper.writeValueAsString(foobeans);
    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {

              etc.
}
```

However, my grid needs an additional column which will contain a valid action for each Foo; that action is not really dependent on any data in individual Foos -- they'll all have the same valid action -- repeated on each line of the resulting DGrid -- but that value is actually dependent upon security roles on the session...**which can't be sent to the front end in a Json**.  So, my solution is twofold:

1. First I need to add a "virtual" Json property to the bean... which I can do in the bean with @JsonProperty on a method...

   ```
   @JsonProperty("validActions")
   public String writeValidActions {
        return "placeHolderForSerializerToChange";
   }
   ```
2. ...but it just generates a placeholder.  To really generate a valid value, 
   I need to reference the security role of the session,
   which I am very reluctant to code in the above method. (A service call in 
   the domain bean itself? Seems very wrong.)  I
   think I should create a custom serializer and put the logic -- and the reference
   to the Session.Security role in there.  Are my instincts right, not to
   inject session info into a domain bean method?  And if so, what would such a
   custom serializer look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I wouldn't put Session Info in to the domain or access session directly in my domain.

Unless there is a specific reason, you could simply add the logic in your action class.

```
public String clickDisplayFoos(){
    List<Foo> foos =  service.getFoos();
    for(iterate through foos){
        foo.setValidAction(session.hasSecurityRole())
    }
    String json = objMapper.writeValueAsString(foobeans);
    return json;
}
```

I don't like the idea of setting new values as part of the serialization process. I feel custom serializers are meant to transform the representation of a particular property rather than add new values to a property.

Comment: I agree with your discomfort at a "virtual" Json property in a domain bean, Sashi.  I see that there is, in addition to object-relational impedance mismatch, domain Object-UI Object impedance mismatch...or something akin to it.  Time to hit a Java blog to hash out these ideas.  Thanks!